# Make Tesseract theme header fixed for all pages

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I'm constructing a website using the Tesseract theme by Tyler Moore. I want to make the header fixed and 80% opaque for every page of the website. The header for the home page has a slider for transparency under customization and I managed to make it fixed by changing its position by editing the site-banner css file in cpanel. My question is, how can I apply the same setting to all the other pages of my website? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

On the wordpress dashbord, hover on the appearance tab, then click on editor. On the right, select stylesheet. Then paste this code at the end of the stylesheet.

```
#masthead_TesseractTheme {
position: fixed;
margin:auto;
z-index:100000;
opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Then click Update file.

[Click here the see the Procedure on how to locate and edit the stylesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7ozZ.png)